# How to get the output value of for loop in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Hi i am getting the values from a dynamically created input form with following loop.

i need to store the for loop out put value to be stored in an array like below

```
points= [[0,420],[10,373],[20,340],[30,313],[40,293],[50,273],[60,259],[70,243]]
```

my for loop code

```
//for example intId = 4
for(i=0;i<intId;i++){
        var it=i+1
        var af = $('#af'+it).val()
        var sp = $('#sp'+it).val()
        var ad = [af,sp]
        console.log(ad);
    }
```

i need the result in this format as mentioned above
for eg.

```
[[af1,sp1],[af2,sp2],[af3,sp3],...]
```

Comment: ... append the information to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something exceptionally obvious here, all you need to do is create an array, and then [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the new arrays into it...

```
var newArray = [];
for (i=0;i<intId;i++){
    var it=i+1
    var af = $('#af'+it).val()
    var sp = $('#sp'+it).val()
    var ad = [af,sp]
    newArray.push(ad);
}
console.log(newArray);
```

---

As per the comment by the OP...

> i need the output like this [2, 3] [1, 2] but i am getting like this ["2", "3"] ["1", "2"]

Then use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get the actual number...

```
var newArray = [];
for (i=0;i<intId;i++){
    var it=i+1
    var af = parseInt($('#af'+it).val())
    var sp = parseInt($('#sp'+it).val())
    var ad = [af,sp]
    newArray.push(ad);
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks.. but i need the output like this  [2, 3] [1, 2] but i am getting like this ["2", "3"] ["1", "2"]

Comment: @DanielGale i = 1 is a cool idea but in out put it is throwing only i-1 time of values

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked well.. Also one more doubt how to sort the array in ascending or descending order in the output

Comment: Consider the [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method on the array, passing in a `compareFunction`

Comment: If you throw that line out then change your for to `i=1;i<=intId;i++`, with attention to the comparison also.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and store the values in the array.

```js
const arr = [] // Initialize an empty array
for(i=0;i<intId;i++){
    var it = i+1
    var af = $('#af'+it).val()
    var sp = $('#sp'+it).val()
    var ad = [af,sp]
    arr.push(ad); // Append to array
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Great Working, but i need the values as numbers its pushing as string like this
["2", "3"]
["1", "2"]

Comment: Just convert `af` and `sp` from string to a number before pushing in the array. Like this, `var ad = [Number(af),Number(sp)]`, assuming `af` and `sp` always represents a valid number in string form.